# How to get the gradients with respect to a matrix?

Tags: derivatives

I found a formula

$$ \mathbb{G} = \frac{\lambda_1}{2} tr(WW^\mathrm{ T }) +  \frac{\lambda_2}{2} tr(W{\Omega}^{-1} W^\mathrm{ T })$$

Where $W$ is a $n \times m$ matrix and $\Omega$ is a $m \times m$ matrix.

And the gradient of $\mathbb{G}$ with respect to $W$ is

$$ \frac{\partial{\mathbb{G}}}{\partial{W}}=W(\lambda_1 I_m + \lambda_2 \Omega^{-1})$$

Where $I_m$ is $m \times m $ identity matrix.

How can I get the $ \frac{\partial{\mathbb{G}}}{\partial{W}}$ when $W$ is a matrix?

Comment: The [Gâteux-Derivative](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gâteaux-Differential) should work here.

Comment: @P.Siehr Gâteaux. (gâteux = senile, in French.)

Comment: @Did, I think my question is clear. Could you please tell me why my question is not clear since P. Siehr has already understood my question and gave a useful answer.

Comment: Indeed, a clear mathematical problem, which is fully answered in every textbook on the subject and which has no context from you. Even after you received an answer, I am unable to determine where you have trouble in this. (Unrelated: Why the honor of being selected to give you explanations about the reasons why this was put on hold by 5 users?)

Comment: @Did imo OP has two problems: Understanding what $∂G/∂M$ means, since a derivative w.r.t. a matrix seems to be odd, and how to compute it. Both are included in my answer, but in a way that he needs to work with my answer to fully understand it. Alexander, if that is true I suggest you write that in your question to unlock it. Off-Topic: Did, simply because you commented. That means your name visually appears also in the comment section - and you can be linked using that little pop-up of the name.

Comment: @P.Siehr Hmmm... But this makes no sense. Hence my remark to the OP.

Comment: @P.Siehr, I agree with you that I think getting a derivative w.r.t a matrix is new and hard for me.

Comment: @Did Sorry, what exactly does not make sense?

Comment: @P.Siehr To select a name amongst five using this fortuitous circumstance. No big deal and, once again, thanks for the technical explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the Gâteaux-Derivative works pretty well for this.

I will show this for the first part $G(W)=\operatorname{tr}(WW^\top)$.

---

It is with a direction $δW$ and an increment $ε>0$:
\begin{align*} 
\operatorname{tr}((W+εδW)(W+εδW)^\top &= \operatorname{tr}(WW^\top + εδWW^\top + εWδW^\top + ε^2δWδW^\top) \\
&=\operatorname{tr}(WW^\top) + ε\operatorname{tr}(δWW^\top) + ε\operatorname{tr}(WδW^\top) + ε^2\operatorname{tr}(δWδW^\top)
\end{align*}

Hence we have: 
$$G(W+δW)-G(W) = ε\operatorname{tr}(δWW^\top) + ε\operatorname{tr}(WδW^\top) + ε^2\operatorname{tr}(δWδW^\top)$$

and
$$\frac{G(W+δW)-G(W)}{ε} = \operatorname{tr}(δWW^\top) + \operatorname{tr}(WδW^\top) + ε\operatorname{tr}(δWδW^\top)$$

and with $ε→0$ it follows:
$$\lim_{ε→0}\frac{G(W+δW)-G(W)}{ε} = \operatorname{tr}(δWW^\top) + \operatorname{tr}(WδW^\top) =  2\operatorname{tr}(WδW^\top) =: D(G,δW)$$

Now we know the directional derivative $D(W,δW)$ with respect to an arbitrary matrix $δW$.

The derivative is defined as: 
$$\frac{∂G}{∂W} = \pmatrix{\frac{∂G}{∂W_{11}} & \frac{∂G}{∂W_{12}} & … & \frac{∂G}{∂W_{1n}}\\\frac{∂G}{∂W_{21}} & \frac{∂G}{∂W_{22}} & … & \frac{∂G}{∂W_{2n}} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\ 
\frac{∂G}{∂W_{m1}} & \frac{∂G}{∂W_{m2}} & … & \frac{∂G}{∂W_{mn}}  }$$

with $\frac{∂G}{∂W_{ij}}:=D(G,E_{ij})$, and $E_{ij}$ defined by $[E_{ij}]_{ij}=1$, and 0 everywhere else (canonical basis). This follows the same construction we already know for the gradient of a function. In the same way as $\frac{∂f}{∂x_1}$ is the derivative of $f$ in direction $e_1$, $\frac{∂G}{∂W_{34}}$ is the derivative of $G$ in direction $E_{34}$.

If we plug in $δW=E_{ij}$ we get: 
$$W^\top E_{ij} = (0|…|0|\underbrace{W^\top_i}_{j}|0|…|0),$$
that has the $i$-th column of $W^\top$ in the column $j$.

Hence, we get:
$$D(W,E_{ij})=2\operatorname{tr}(W^\top E_{ij})=2[W^\top]_{ji}=2w_{ij}.$$

Putting everything together yields: 
$$\frac{∂G}{∂W} = 2W = 2WI_m$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Changed the notation of the matrix form $W_{ij}$ to $E_{ij}$, which resembles more the $e_i$ basis vector.